# "Mirroring" an angle

Tags: math, function, trigonometry, angle

I need to obtain the supplement of an angle.

Exactly what I need to do is to implement some kind of code that mirror the angle, let's say, I have 45 degrees -> 135, another example: 80 ->100, 0 degrees -> 180, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're after `180 - yourAngle`.

Your examples:

- 45 degrees:   180 - 45 = 135
- 80 degrees:   180 - 80 = 100
- 0 degrees:    180 - 0  = 180

Comment: Yes, that worked ok but, what if my angle is 225?, if I do that then I'll get 180 - 225 = -45, and I should get 135.

Maybe I should use 360 - angle if my angle is > 180.

Comment: @Artemix: So normalize the angle between 0 and 180 (by adding/subtraction 180 until you are between [0, 180) )

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I'm asking if am'I correct if I do 360 - myAngle when myAngle > 180.

Comment: @Artemix: you are doing your arithmetic mod 180, so adding 360 is the same as adding 180. That is, `(360-angle) mod 180 = (180-angle) mod 180 = (-angle) mod 180`. Here I am using mod in the mathematical sense, where `(-1 mod 180) = 179`, not +1. Thus, even multiplying your angle by -1 and adding/subtracting 180 until you are between [0, 180) will give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Subtraction will probably work (if the universe is Euclidean).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_angles

Answer (score 3):

```
mirrored_Angle = 180 - angle

if mirrored_Angle < 0:
    mirrored_Angle = 360 + mirrored_Angle
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer, based on what you appear to be asking about is

```
angle2 = 180 - angle1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
reflected_angle = 180 - ray_angle
```

Answer (score 1):

If you view your "angle" as a 2D vector in the plane, you simply change the sign of the component normal to the "mirror" plane.

So, for example, a 45 degree angle (1, 1) "mirrored" in the yz-plane becomes (-1, 1).

Comment: Yes, that was EXACTLY what I thought in the first place, but when I tryied to do that on the code, I found some problems. Thing is, I didnt find a way to "reconstruct" the angle using the new components.

Comment: Post your code, because this is exactly correct.  The problem was in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with a rope physics project of mine and used this to mirror angles.

```
mirroredAngle = -(yourAngle % 360)
```

This will work with values over 360 degrees because the modulus operation normalizes your angle, and subtracting that result from 0 will mirror it horizontally.